# Extending representations from a closed Lie subgroup - solution verification

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $H$ a closed Lie subgroup. Let $i : H \hookrightarrow G$ denote the inclusion. Then given any finite-dimensional representation $\rho : H \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is it possible to find a finite-dimensional extension of $\rho$ to the whole group $G$, i.e. a finite-dimensional representation $\tilde{\rho} : G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(W)$ such that the following diagram commutes

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H @>{\rho}>> \mathrm{GL}(V)\\
@ViVV @VVjV \\
G @>{\tilde{\rho}}>> \mathrm{GL}(W)
\end{CD}$$
where $j$ is injective.

$\textbf{Proposed solution:}$

Since we work with compact groups only, we can assume first that $\rho$ is irreducible. Then $\mathrm{ind}^G_H(\rho)$ defines a unitary representation of $G$, which we can write as a direct sum of finite-dimensional irreducible representations:

$\mathrm{ind}^G_H(\rho) = \bigoplus_{\alpha} \mu_{\alpha}$

The classical Frobenius reciprocity theorem states that given irreducible representations $\pi$ of $G$ and $\rho$ of $H$
we have that $\rho \subset \mathrm{res}^G_H(\pi)$ is a sub-representation if and only if $\pi \subset \mathrm{ind}^G_H(\rho)$ is contained in the induced representation.

Choosing now $\pi = \mu_{\alpha}$ we have by assumption:
$\mu_{\alpha} \subset \mathrm{ind}^G_H(\rho)$ hence $\rho \subset \mathrm{res}^G_H(\mu_{\alpha})$. Therefore choose $\tilde{\rho} := \mathrm{res}^G_H(\mu_{\alpha})$ which is indeed finite-dimensional and the above diagram commutes.

If $\rho$ is not irreducible write it as a finite direct sum of irreducible ones, since $H$ is compact.

Comment: This question could be improved if you were to add your thoughts to it.  What have you tried?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I have edited my question and added my thoughts to it.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, I just reread the question and realized I don't know how to help after all....

Comment: @JasonDeVito Well thank you anyway, I appreciate your feedback.